# Program to tell what scripts are running in a browser?

Tags: javascript

Is there a program that tells me the script that a browser executes for a particular event? for example, what script clicking on a button initiates?

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools. They have event listener breakpoints.

Comment: Developer tools at Chrome, Firebug at FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Event](https://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual%20Event) bookmarklet enables you to see DOM0 event bound to individual elements.

[image]
<sub>(source: [myopera.com](http://files.myopera.com/c69/blog/visual_event_at_google.png))</sub>

Webkit's WebInspector has EventListener inspector module.. but it often crashes Chrome, when you try to use it.